# C compiler - list __builtin_ types

Tags: c, typedef, built-in

here is a small (and working) C code:

```
typedef __builtin_va_list __va_list;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I found an answer, how gcc found the base type:
[Pycparser not working on preprocessed code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983726/pycparser-not-working-on-preprocessed-code/28992259#28992259)

But how can I list all of the __builtin_ "base" types, which not defined explicitly?

Thanks,
a.

Comment: Presumably by looking at the source code of the gcc version you're using.

Comment: Why is it useful to do so?

Comment: Your "working" code gives me a syntax error "C2061: syntax error: identifier '__va_list'".

Comment: @melphone: thanks, that's the latest option :)

Comment: @John Bollinger: I'm working on a project, which needs to parse types

Comment: @Weather Vane: which C compiler do you use on which platform? I've tested on Linux, with GCC 4.9.2

Comment: @melpomene: it's not an option, because those items aren't same in different versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I list all of the __builtin_ "base" types, which not defined explicitly?

**TL;DR**: there is no general-purpose way to do it.

The standard does not define any such types, so they can only be implementation-specific.  In particular, C does not attribute any significance to the `__builtin_` name prefix (though such identifiers are reserved), nor does it acknowledge that any types exist that are not derived from those it does define.  Thus, for most purposes, the types you are asking about should be considered an implementation detail.

If there were a way to list implementation-specific built-in types, it would necessarily be implementation-specific itself.  For example, you might be able to find a list such as you are after in the compiler's documentation.  You could surely derive one from the compiler's own source code, if that's available to you.  You could maybe extract strings from the compiler binary, and filter for a characteristic name pattern, such as strings starting with "__builtin_".

You could also consider parsing all the standard library headers (with the assumption that they are correct) to find undeclared types, though that's not guaranteed to find *all* the available types.  Moreover, with some systems, for example GNU's, the C standard library (to which the headers belong) is separate from the compiler.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the answer. I thought there is a switch for gcc/cpp, which lists those types, like "-dM" does. Anyway, I found these types in source of GCC, but I'm afraid the idea, that I can catch these by I search the pattern \_\_builtin_ is not enough. There are several other names, eg. \_\_complex, \_\_complex__, and so on. It's interesting the relation between the C compiler and standard headers. Take a look the "stdarg.h" header. That contains a typedef, which referenced to __builtin_va_list. So, what's happened, when I'ld like to use LLVM or Intel C comp., instead of GCC?

Comment: @airween, indeed, what *does* happen when you switch compilers?  Answer: anything implementation-specific in your program must detect the change (and have appropriate alternative behavior ready) or else will likely break.  That is why I summarized my answer as I did: "there is no general-purpose way to do it."  The best alternative is to avoid implementation-specific entanglements.

Comment: And note, that gcc's `-dM` option is implementation specific, too, just as an option that did what you want would be.  There are commonly-implemented compiler options, especially among alternative toolchains targeting the same platform, but there is no general standard for C compiler options.  The closest are the POSIX specifications for commands `c89` and `c99`, but they do not describe a `-dM` option.

Comment: thanks for your answers again - I've reviewed the headers, and stdarg.h is part of GCC - so, looks like that header is not part of libc, but part of C compiler. Now that's clear.

Comment: the `-dM` option is just an example. I thought it would be better to list the __builtin_ (and similar) types for GNU gcc. May be that another compiler tools doesn't have `-dM`, but gcc has. Nevermind, I think now it's clear for all thing, I can go away in my project. Many thanks for your help!